# How to make a dynamic With reference?

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

How do I make a dynamic With reference to a sheet?

```
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim rng As Range

SelectedSystem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blabla").Range("AI2").Value

'I would like to change this to a version like the one below,
' where I reference the selected system rather than a specific sheet.
With Sheet2
    lr2 = Worksheets("Blabla" & SelectedSystem & " Blabla").Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Worksheets("Blabla" & SelectedSystem & " Blabla").Range("H2:H" & lr2)
End With
```

Comment: Create a worksheet object, so `dim w as excel.worksheet` then `set w=Worksheets("Blabla" & SelectedSystem & " Blabla")` and then use `with w`

Comment: Just use `With Worksheets("Blabla" & SelectedSystem & " Blabla")`

Comment: In VBA you need to declare all variables - even though in your Workbook there is a Worksheet which is named "Sheet2" it doesn't mean that you can directly use that as an object in your VBA code. As the guys ^ said. Declare the Sheet2 object and then use in your code.

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos  He can if ‘Sheet2’ is the codename of the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `worksheet` object,

so

`dim w as excel.worksheet`

then

`set w=Worksheets("Blabla" & SelectedSystem & " Blabla")`

and then use `with w`